# How bind touch event to i3wm?

Tags: touchscreen, i3-window-manager

Is it possible to `bindsym` a `MotionNotify event` in i3 config?

Something like:

```
bindsym MotionNotify button1 kill
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try running `xev`, and taking note of what keys are mapped to your touch events. It may be that you need to specify more specifically the keycode for the touch events, especially if they're registered as XF86 keys. I don't have a touch-enabled computer, so sorry I can't be of more help.